# array of constant pointers

Tags: c++

Ok, I know that this is invalid

```
 char char_A = 'A';
    const char * myPtr = &char_A;
    *myPtr = 'J'; // error - can't change value of *myP
```

[Because we declared a pointer to a constant character]

Why is this valid?

```
 const char  *linuxDistro[6]={ "Debian", "Ubuntu", "OpenSuse", "Fedora", "Linux Mint", "Mandriva"};

for ( int i=0; i < 6; i++) 
cout << *(linuxDistro+i)<< endl;

*linuxDistro="WhyCanIchangeThis";// should result in an error but doesnt ? 
for ( int i=0; i < 6; i++) 
cout << *(linuxDistro+i)<< endl;
```

Thanks for looking!

Comment: So now is this C or C++?

Comment: c++ my bad. I removed the C tag.

Comment: thanks everyone for your replies, you guys are amazing!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You write

```
*linuxDistro =  "WhyCanIchangeThis";
```

which is **perfectly valid,** because the declaration of `linuxDistro` was

```
const char *linuxDistro[6];
```

i. e. it's an array of 6 pointers to `const char`. That is, you **can** change the pointers *themselves,* just not the *characters pointed to* by those pointers. I. e., you **can not compile**

```
*linuxDistro[0] = 'B';
```

to obtain the string `"Bebian"`, becuse the strings contain constant characters...

What you probably want is an array of constant pointers to constant characters:

```
const char *const linuxDistro[6];
```

Comment: isn't *linusDistro and *linuxDistro[0] the same?

Comment: @Ashwin No. Why would it be?

Comment: the name of the array holds the memory location of the first element of the array.

Comment: I am not trying to teach you C, first of all. I was just trying to learn. You sound like a man with a big ego.

Comment: @Ashwin I deleted my comment, but please... don't do this here. There are plenty of papers on this topic. This a far bigger theme than being suited for a comment.

Comment: for the record, *linuxDistro[0]='B' crashes during runtime even when i remove const from *linuxdistro

Comment: @Illusionist: That's because you initialized it using string literals. String literals cannot be changed, and the compiler implicitly stripped away the `const` qualifier. (If warnings were on, it would tell you about this.)

Answer (score 3):

*linuxDistro is still a pointer, it is linuxDistro[0], `*linuxDistro="WhyCanIchangeThis"` it just change the pointer to point to a new address, not to modify the content in the old address, so it is OK.

If you write `**linuxDistro='a'`, it should error.

Answer (score 1):

because `char` is not `char[]`, so when you access to `*` of `char[]` you access the first element of it (Debian).

when you shift pointer (e.g. +1 it) you access next element of array

here is good example for better understanding

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  int numbers[5];
  int * p;
  p = numbers;  *p = 10;
  p++;  *p = 20;
  p = &numbers[2];  *p = 30;
  p = numbers + 3;  *p = 40;
  p = numbers;  *(p+4) = 50;
  for (int n=0; n<5; n++)
    cout << numbers[n] << ", ";
  return 0;
}
```

this will output:

> 10, 20, 30, 40, 50,

Answer (score 1):

because the pointer is a variable that stores a memory address, if a pointer is `const` the pointer keeps storing the same memory address, so the value of the pointer itself can't change, but you are saying nothing about the value pointed by the pointer, according to what you have, chaging the pointed value it's an allowed operation.